# Shopping Price rule for a fixed amount

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I'm trying to set up a coupon where if "You purchase $350 or more, enter coupon, receive $50 off".

I've created the coupon "Holiday50"

The condition I entered:

```
"Subtotal equals or greater than 350"
```

The actions I entered:

```
 Apply: "Fixed amount discount"
 Discount Amount: "50"
```

When I tested the coupon, it's discounting the items 100%. The order would come to $0.00 and I only want it to discount $50. I don't have any other rules set up so nothing should be interfering with that.
Is this a common issue and how would I fixed it??

Thanks!

[Edit] - So I noticed that whenever the qty > 1, this will not work but if qty = 1 then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to select the option ' Apply fixed amount discount for whole cart'. The option you selected will apply the discount to every single item in the order.

Comment: Sometimes I over look the little things, thank you! This worked!